# How to Fetch API Using ES6

Tags: javascript, post, ecmascript-6, api-design

I'm very new to API and ES6. How will i able to post the username and password and get a response if it is incorrect. BTW, this site is not working.

```js
    fetch('http://thisissamplewebsite.com', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: document.getElementById('email').value
        answer: document.getElementById('answer').value
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consume API</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email"  value="aaa@yahoo.com"/>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password"  value="12345"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You misspelled method in your html code

Comment: They have a really good documentation for fetch. Look here https://github.github.io/fetch/

Comment: @Colin. Can you help me structure this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your code:

1. You misspelled `method` in your html form
2. You are passing an invalid JSON object. You missed one `,` between the objects. But anyway `document.getElementById('answer').value` you have no element with answer as its id.
3. (You snipped wont work because you didn't include the fetch library)
4. (remove the `<script>` tag in the js area in your snippet. they are not necessary)
5. The snippet would also not work properly because the API URL does not respond.

Check out the documentation of fetch for more information. [fetch on github](https://github.com/github/fetch)

```js
fetch('http://thisissamplewebsite.com', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: document.getElementById('email').value
        //answer: document.getElementById('answer').value
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consume API</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email"  value="aaa@yahoo.com"/>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password"  value="12345"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

server response will return as `response.text()`

```
fetch('http://example.com', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: document.getElementById('email').value,
    password: document.getElementById('password').value
  }).then(function(response) {
    alert(response.text());
    //document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = response.text();
  }, 
  function(error) {
    // handle network error
  })
});
```

Comment: your code wont work because you are trying to put the then part after the `JSON.stringify()` function. It must be after the `fetch()` function.